# How to use jenkinsfile to get content from AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-sqs

Could you share me jenkinsfile example for get value from AWS SQS? I have a message in queue. I know using sqs plugin to trigger when a message is published from sqs, but I don't know how to get it in jenkinsfile​. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can import standard AWS SDK to your file as

```
@Grab('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.298')
import ......
```

and feel free to use it whenever you need